# How to get PoseBone local axis direction vectors in world space?

Tags: python, animation, bones, mathematics

To get a bone's local Y direction vector in world space all I have to do is: `PoseBone.tail - PoseBone.head`

Now what is the formula to also get X and Z direction vectors?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there’s already a variable for that in PoseBone called `x_axis`, `y_axis`, `z_axis`.